# Why won't trauma to the lungs/heart kill zombies?

Tags: zombie, patient-zero

In Jonathan Maberry's *Patient Zero*, the zombification disease functions by making the host enter a deep hibernative state when they are close to dying, then waking them up again after shutting down parts of the body that are severely damaged or not necessary for the zombie's survival. The zombies have super-regenerative abilities which helps them seal up wounds almost instantly and it is stated that they can only be killed by damage to the brain.

However the book also says that zombies still breathe and their hearts are still pumping blood, albeit at a minimum rate, so shouldn't the zombies be vulnerable to body shots too?

Comment: Because of their '*super-regenerative abilities which helps them seal up wounds almost instantly*'?

Comment: @Valorum Well, yeah, but if I take a shotgun and shoot them in the chest point blank it would still destroy the lungs and heart regardless of any super healing ability, right?

Comment: Depends how super the super-healing is.

Comment: Well it can't instantly grow back organs that's for sure, it just stops the bleeding.

Comment: Well, even that is fantastical, so who's to say how it works?

Comment: it wouldn't be science fiction if it doesn't explain things in a science fiction way.

Comment: Someone voted to close this question because it is "opinion based". Dude like what why how does that make sense

Comment: I wouldn't worry about what single users do.

Comment: Okay so Dead of Night (which was written by the same author so I'm gonna assume it happened in the same universe) mentions something about the parasites using a network of larvae connected with mucus to prevent death from oxygen starvation but it is very vague. Does anyone here know if the author ever further elaborates on this?